# postgis get geometries within a radius of meters using wgs84

Tags: gis, postgis, wgs84

```
select *
from zones z
where st_intersects(z.geom, st_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(     2.336031, 48.863172), 3857),1));
```

It looks like the '1' in the st_buffer is being interpreted as degrees, I need to find geometries within n meters of a given point.

I did find a reference to a new function (st_Buffer_Meters) but that didn't seem to do anything different.

Comment: perhaps this would be better suited to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Probably, I'll go do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual query that ended up working was:

```
 select nom
 from zones s
 where ST_DWITHIN(Geography(ST_Transform(s.geom,4326)), ST_Point($1, $2) ,$3);`
```

Where $1 is Longitude, $2 is Latitude and $3 is distance in meters.

In addition I changed my imported data from SRID 3857 to SRID 4326

Here's the gis.stackexchange question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118472/postgis-get-geometries-within-a-radius-of-n-meters-using-wgs84/118476#118476

And here's the 'This has been asked before link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77688/postgis-get-the-points-that-are-x-meters-near-another-point-in-meters

Answer (score 0):

First, I simplified your query to use a distance function, which will do the same thing as your query performs with fewer words. [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) will return the minimum distance between two geometries in meters. However I had some difficulty in using your SRID so I use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to transform the SRID to [4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)

```
select *
from zones z
where st_distance_sphere(z.geom, 
     ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point( 2.336031, 48.863172), 3857), 4326  
)< 1000;
```

Comment: I got some good advice from gis.stackexchange and solved the issue.  Specifically I changed my original data import from srid 3857 to 4326 and that made everything substantially simpler.  gis also had existing answers http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77688/postgis-get-the-points-that-are-x-meters-near-another-point-in-meters